# Is there a way for textract to render pdf images to excel data tables?

Tags: ocr

I have a pdf of a data table, but it is only an image. meaning, I can't copy and paste value from it and OCR isn't available. Is there a way to use textract (or some other service) to get the data table to excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use textract for parts of this, but there's no way to structure the results well. For example, you can make one long list the text blocks containing "line" but you would need a way to structure them similarly to how they were structured in the original data table from the PDF. That last part in particular makes this problem quite challenging.